# Can kernel initiate write to sequential file?

Tags: c, file, linux-kernel, sequential

My [understanding](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/seq_file.txt) is that sequential files (represented by `struct seq_file`) are an interface to transfer data between kernel and user process without any physical manifestation of the file on disk. When a user reads the sequential file (given it is readable), the associated kernel read function transfers data to a buffer (which the interface has allocated), from where the user process then reads.

**My question:** Can the kernel call the read function without any initiation from user space?

**My goal:** I want a user process to wait for an inotify event on a change to a particular sequential file.

Please correct me if my understanding is wrong. Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with using `vfs_read` function, as for general file's reading in the kernel? It will care about everything.

Comment: sysfs? sysfs_notify?

Answer (score 0):

Seq_files are mainly used for batch mode read by user space from /proc. The seq file interface views the contents of /proc files as a sequence of objects. If there is read request from user e.g., reading log buffers, static/ dynamic information related to processes and memory, kernel invokes related read request and puts to user buffer, hence req from user space is required.

Also I am not sure about your purpose of notify. Generally kernel doesn't care if the logged info user reads from /proc is up-to-date or not. By doesn't care, I mean it doesn't do any version keeping for it. Typical example is execution of `ls`. while listing directory content, things can change. Kernel goes on reading the snapshot of directory at that particular time though it was updated immediately after read and before it was displayed to user.